# CORS error executing JavaScript function in Flutter WebView

Tags: angularjs, flutter, cors

I'm trying to load an AngularJS web in a Flutter application using WebViewController, the page is loading but throw an error when I try to make a call to a JavaScript function. The wen is located in the assets of my application.

- ### These are the assets in my flutter aplicacion:

```
assets:
    - assets/img/
    - assets/www/index.html
// ... here are the rests of the assets.
```

- ### This is the function that I'm using to initialize the WebView and load the web page:

```
void initializeWebView() async {
    _controller
    ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
    ..setBackgroundColor(const Color(0x00000000))
    ..setNavigationDelegate(
      NavigationDelegate(
        onProgress: (int progress) {},
        onPageStarted: (String url) {},
        onPageFinished: (String url) {},
        onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {},
        onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
          return NavigationDecision.navigate;
        },
      ),
    )
    ..loadFlutterAsset('assets/www/index.html');
    _controller.runJavaScriptReturningResult('''
      window.jsCall = function(data) {
        window.flutter_injector.postMessage(JSON.stringify(data));
      };
    ''').then((value){
      log( value.toString() );
    });
    _controller.runJavaScriptReturningResult('jsCall()').then((value) {
      log( value.toString() );
      Message actionData = jsonDecode(value.toString());
      callMethod(actionData);
    });

    // Establece un listener para escuchar mensajes desde el WebView
    _controller.addJavaScriptChannel('flutter_injector',
        onMessageReceived: (message) {
      log("Mensaje desde el WebView: $message");
    });
  }
```

### This is the error that I'm getting:##

I/chromium( 6262): [INFO:CONSOLE(123)] "Possibly unhandled rejection: en", source: file:///android_asset/flutter_assets/assets/www/scripts/angular/angular.min.js (123)
E/FrameEvents( 6262): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
I/chromium( 6262): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///android_asset/flutter_assets/assets/www/images/icons/ic_menu_white_24px.svg' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-untrusted, https.", source: file:///android_asset/flutter_assets/assets/www/index.html#/app (0)
I/chromium( 6262): [INFO:CONSOLE(123)] "Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","cache":{},"url":"images/icons/ic_menu_white_24px.svg","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":""}", source: file:///android_asset/flutter_assets/assets/www/scripts/angular/angular.min.js (123)
I/chromium( 6262): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///android_asset/flutter_assets/assets/www/partials/main/app-loading.html' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-untrusted, https.", source: file:///android_asset/flutter_assets/assets/www/index.html#/app (0)
I/chromium( 6262): [INFO:CONSOLE(123)] "Error: [$compile:tpload] [http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.3/$compile/tpload?p0=partials%2Fmain%2Fapp-loading.html&p1=-1&p2="](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.3/$compile/tpload?p0=partials%2Fmain%2Fapp-loading.html&p1=-1&p2=%22), source: file:///android_asset/flutter_assets/assets/www/scripts/angular/angular.min.js (123)
E/FrameEvents( 6262): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
D/EGL_emulation( 6262): app_time_stats: avg=272.97ms min=26.90ms max=794.33ms count=4
E/FrameEvents( 6262): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.

I have been looking around but can't found anything and I have no experience with angular and I can't figure how to solve this issues.

Any help that you can gime I'll appreciate it.
Thanks in advance.